# Using a Binding in the Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

This may well have been asked and answered before but I really wasn't sure how to phrase the question.

I have a dictionary (MyLookup) and I want a control to bind to a particular key and value in the dictionary. The key for the dictionary is a string, and lets say the particular item is 'MyItem'. The output should be something like:

```
MyItem value: 43
```

One idea was to use a couple of text blocks and a tack panel, one for the key and one for the value. I tried to encapsulate the item of interest in the stack panel, but things get fruity when defining the binding path for the second text block

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tag="MyItem">
  <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, StringFormat={0} value:}"/>
  <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Path=MyLookup[{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}]}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

It might also be possible to do it with a single text block and some string formatting?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyLookup[MyItem], StringFormat={0} value: {1}}"/>
```

Bleugh, it all falls apart there as there need to be 2 outputs?! My current thinking is to use a multi-converter to take the string and convert it to a string and an int, but I was wondering if thee were cunning things that I'm missing.

Comment: Create a proper ViewModel for this and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: @HighCore +1 for that all problems solving recipe. step one - create a property viewmodel, step two - lean back and watch your problems disappear magically :)

Comment: @devhedgehog it's not a "property viewmodel" (whatever that means). I said "Proper ViewModel", which means the OP should organize his data adequately in a separate class instead of expecting the UI to be able to process this convoluted dictionary stuff.

Comment: @HighCore PROPER.. Sorry I cant type :)

Answer (score 2):

Once again, *A `Binding` can only be set on a `DependencyProperty` of a `DependencyObject`*. You're trying to use a `Binding` for the integer that specifies which key/value to look at from your `Dictionary`, but you can't because it is an integer and not a `DependencyProperty`.

Instead of doing this, you should create a view model that contains all of the data and functionality that your view requires. As @HighCore mentioned, once you have organised your data in the right way, then all of these nasty problems will disappear.

Comment: OMG 11k? when did you get so rich out of nowhere? Last time I checked you were 6K. I'm starting to fear you dude...

Comment: LOL, that's because I keep answering questions instead of just commenting like you do. ;) Plus, I got a bit addicted to this a while back, but I think I've recovered from that now. :)

Comment: yeah, I got lazy as hell lately. I only do those *"look what WPF can do and winforms can't"* / full sample type of answers.

Comment: Cor mate... `WinForms` must have hurt you badly when you were a child or something. :) There's definitely something about answering the same old questions again and again that puts me off too... and there's nothing worse than taking the time to fully explain something when the user just doesn't get it and keeps coming back with follow up questions. I'm starting to slack off a bit too now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what the h**k is this `{Binding Path=MyLookup[{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}]}`

Take a look at ObjectDataProvider.

That bad ass allows you do craziest Bindings you can think of and all that is happening in XAML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It's not 'real' code, it's just an expression of the sort of thing that I was wondering about might be possible.

Comment: It is possible with ObjectDataProvider